# Initialize an property with data from a block

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks

I want to initialize a CLLocationCoordinate2D property with a variable in a block.

in my company.h file:

```
@property CLLocationCoordinate2D cllocation;
```

in my company.m file

```
NSString *addressComplete = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %d %@", address,(int) plz, place];
    [self convertAddress:addressComplete];

-(void)convertAddress:(NSString*) address
{
    NSString *location = address;
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geocoder geocodeAddressString:location
                 completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
                     if (placemarks && placemarks.count > 0) {
                         CLPlacemark *topResult = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                         MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithPlacemark:topResult];
                         _cllocation.longitude = placemark.location.coordinate.longitude;
                         _cllocation.latitude = placemark.location.coordinate.latitude;

                     }
                 }
     ];
    NSLog(@"longitude: %f", _cllocation.longitude);

}
```

NSLog shows _cllocation as 0.0000.

How can i get this to work?

Comment: This is because statements in block are the execute after NSLog statement.

Comment: that kind of issue was raised many time on this forum... :( about the connection between _block's content_ and the _outside environment of the block_: briefly, your `NSLog(...)` is executed _before_ your block does run.

Comment: I'd suggest renaming your method to "startConvertingAddress" because that's what it does. It _starts_ the conversion but it will only be finished some time later. BTW. your code is not thread safe. _cllocation.longitude will be set on an unknown thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because statements in block are executed after NSLog statement. You are printing result before assigning. Move NSLog inside the block.

```
-(void)convertAddress:(NSString*) address
{
    NSString *location = address;
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geocoder geocodeAddressString:location
             completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
                 if (placemarks && placemarks.count > 0) {
                     CLPlacemark *topResult = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                     MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithPlacemark:topResult];
                     _cllocation.longitude = placemark.location.coordinate.longitude;
                     _cllocation.latitude = placemark.location.coordinate.latitude;
                     NSLog(@"longitude: %f", _cllocation.longitude);
                 }
             }
     ];
}
```